# Should a parent class be included in child class? PHP

Tags: php, oop

Lets says I have 4 file, 3 of them containing each a class:

**animal.php**

```
class animal
{}
```

**cat.php**

```
class cat extends animal
{}
```

**dog.php**

```
class dog extends animal
{}
```

**main.php**

```
$cat = new cat();
$cat->doSomething();
$dog = new dog();
$dog->runAroundTryToCatchTail();
```

I was wondering if it was better practice to include or require **animal.php** in each of its child class or in **main.php**?

In other words, is it better:

**main.php**

```
require_once('animal.php');
require_once('cat.php');
require_once('dog.php');
$cat = new cat();
$cat->doSomething();
$dog = new dog();
$dog->runAroundTryToCatchTail();
```

**OR**

**dog.php**

```
require_once('animal.php');
class dog extends animal
{}
```

**cat.php**

```
require_once('animal.php');
class dog extends animal
{}
```

**UPDATE**

In fact what I what to know is:

Is there any SOLID principal or GRASP or any other OOP pratice I should consider when choosing where I should include my classes files?

Comment: better practise is to use an autoloader

Comment: Neither, you should use [autoloading](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php).

Comment: @MarkBaker should have think of that... dammit I am stupid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best practice is to use autoloader for loading the required classes and follow the PSR-0 standard.

> Read more about PSR-0

https://github.com/php-fig/fig-standards/blob/master/accepted/PSR-0.md

http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-0/

> Read more about Autoloader

http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php

> How to autoload the file which are following the PSR-0?

http://www.sitepoint.com/autoloading-and-the-psr-0-standard/

---

**Update PSR-0 is deprecated according to**

http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-0/

You can use PSR-4 as new autoloading standard

http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-4/

Comment: @Sebastien i have updated the answer please review, if it does help you mark as accepted :) it would be appreciated